# Otimização de páginas na WEB com Java

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, play-framework

O que eu devo procurar para otimizar a performace no front-end, para fazer minimização de css, js etc. manter o head e trocar só o body? Usando Java e Spring MVC, ou, com Play e Sparks por exemplo.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem votos de fechamento por ser ampla demais. Cada uma dessas coisas que você cita é um problema específico e você não deu muitos detalhes sobre para qual finalidade você quer fazer isso. Entretanto, apesar disso, ela não me parece ser tão ampla assim, uma vez que você está mais é pedindo uma lista dos conceitos genéricos, tais como estão na resposta. E portanto, votei em manter aberta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tratando-se de performance no front-end, existem muitas maneiras de otimização. Com o http/1.1 as principais são:

- minificação e/ou concatenação de arquivos javascript e css
- Compactação de Imagem para reduzir o uso da banda
- Sprite de imagens
- Colocar os javascripts no final do body, pois os mesmos são recursos bloqueantes
- Compactação de HTML
- Cache de arquivos estáticos
- etc...

Para fazer a minificação dos arquivos JS e CSS, atualmente é muito usado o [GRUNT](http://tableless.com.br/grunt-voce-deveria-estar-usando/), o mesmo é um automatizador de tarefas. Existem muitos exemplos na internet sobre o seu uso.
No Entanto, se você estiver mais familiarizado com java, pode usar o [WRO](http://alexo.github.io/wro4j/). que é uma ferramenta para otimização de recursos web.

Já com o http/2 algumas dessas práticas não são necessárias, o protocolo contém características que proporcionam uma boa performance. Vale a pena buscar sobre o assunto, um bom servidor http que implementa este protocolo é o [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/#).

Ex. de site com http/2:http://www.http2demo.io/

Finalizando,uma boa referência para boas práticas de otimização do site é o [Google Insights Rules](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules). Ele contém cada um dos itens que mencionei, e melhor explicado.kkk

Comment: Ah sim, valeu pela referência. Estava procurando uma ferramenta no Java para ajudar com isso, vou ver mais sobre http 2 tbm, já ouvi falar sobre. Sabe de algo como, manter o head e carregar somento o body?

Comment: Quando você fala em manter o head é sobre a tag <head>? O que conheço são somente técnicas de cache para os recursos que normalmente você coloca na tag head. Atualmente eu estou usando bastante SPA, os CSSs e JSs são carregados apenas uma vez, depois tem as chamadas ajax e altero somente as partes que quero do HTML.